# Codeigniter Flashdata gone too early

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'll try to make it short.
When i set flash data like this

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('testing', $somevariable);
```

I should get something like this in session:

```
'flash:new:testing' => string 'Test'
```

And this works.
When I make a new server request it should say

```
'flash:old:testing' => string 'Test'
```

I don't get to this part. Even at first request (while it is still "new") i get `boolean (false)` when trying to get flashdata.
I should mention this is working in wamp, but not on my live site.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you redirecting from the controller function?  Flashdata is removed after a redirect.

Comment: No... i think it's a server issue since it is working ok on local server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange !
Maybe you should check the value of **var_dump($somevariable)** in your live site.